# Match number ending in 1 except when ending in 11

Tags: regex, awk

I need to match any number ending in 1 except numbers ending in 11. I use awk. To illustrate, the correctly working lines are:

```
if ( max ~ /1$/ && max !~ /11$/ ) { print max }
```

or using regex:

```
if ( max ~ /[^1]1$|^1$/ ) { print max }
```

or a much slower variant of the same regex:

```
([^1]|^)1$
```

I actualy suspect just this one part (with a modification) should work somehow. It is nice and short and readable, does the job in far less steps than the above combos, works for all numbers with 2 digits of more, but fails for 1 itself. Which I fixed above, but would prefer a better one (if there is). I actually need it to work for 1 to 3 digit numbers, but would prefer to not limiting it.

```
[^1]1$
```

As soon as I try quantifers to fix it, it fails to work correctly. It either starts picking leading 1s (e.g. 1211 is matched and it should not) or loose a single digit number 1 as a match. Obviously, my problem is lying in the fact I must match the end of the number. How to make a better regex?

Test cases:
Matching numbers are:
1
21
31
121
131
1021

skip (not match) numbers ending in 11 like:
11
111
211
1011
1211

Comment: What is the problem with your regex?

Comment: `([^1]|^)1$` matches `1` string, or any string that ends with any char but `1` and then `1`. It works as per your requirements. [This is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/krgXBm/1) of your regex. Note that the first `1` test case in your question contains a space right after `1`. If you plan to support trailing whitespace, write the pattern as `([^1]|^)1[[:space:]]*$` / `([^1]|^)1\s*$`

Comment: @Plia, kindly always add sample Input and sample output in your posts for the better understanding of question.

Comment: ^1$ or ^21$ are matches, there is no space in front of "1" as in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do, I believe it is quicker than a regex parsing:

If you know `max` is a number:

```
if ( max%10 == 1 && max%100 != 11 ) { print max }
```

If you do not know `max` is a number:

```
if ( max+0==max && max%10 == 1 && max%100 != 11 ) { print max }
```

If you want a regex, you can use `^[0-9]*[02-9]1$|^1$` but this is just an extension of RavinderSingh13's answer to make sure it is a number.

Comment: This will match `22`  that is not wanted.

Comment: @Toto sorry, overlooked that part. Updated.

Comment: This is actually an ecellent idea! I will need some further testing to verify speeds. But, I wanted primarily to learn regex. I do have two solutions but lack knowledge :)

Comment: timed it: this one runs 1.09 sec, while my initial ifs run 1.55 and 1.66 sec! So, this is by far the fastest solution! Learned another thing :)

Comment: @Pila, if you like this answer, don't forget [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @kvantour: from a programmer's point: this answer is brilliant and far superior to using regex in this case. From my Q point: this did not improve my regex skill. I still hope for comment if my original regex [^1]1$|^1$ can be improved or not.

Answer (score 1):

If your Input_file is same as shown sample then following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk  '/[02-9]1$/||/^1$/' Input_file
```

Let's say following is the sample Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
1
2001
21
31
121
131
1021
11
111
211
1011
1211
```

Then following will be output after running the code.

```
awk  '/[02-9]1$/||/^1$/'  Input_file
1
2001
21
31
121
131
1021
```

Comment: That is the same solution as my original regex in my question.

Comment: @Pila, regex doesn't meet with your regex, could you please confirm if is working for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. But adds only complexity to my initial version and is slower than my original regex (1.65 vs 1.99 sec). As I said, input is always a number.